# How to assemble variable by string

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following shell script, let's say its' name test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
b_x='it is the value of bx'
c_x='it is the value of cx'

case "$1" in
    "b")
       echo $1_x    # it's doesn't work; I want to echo $b_x
       ;;
     "c")
       echo $1_x   # it's doesn't work; I want to echo $c_x
       ;;
esac
```

And then I want to call the script;

```
./test.sh  b    # I want the output is "it is the value of bx"
./test.sh  c    # I want the output is "it is the value of cx"
```

Comment: What is the question? What is your current output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `case`. Just use indirect variable name expansion:

```
b_x='it is the value of bx'
c_x='it is the value of cx'

var="${1}_x"
echo "${!var}"
```

Then run it as:

```
$> bash test.sh b
it is the value of bx

$> bash test.sh c
it is the value of cx
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to use a variable to name a variable. The standard POSIX method would be to use `eval`.

```
$ a_x="Hello world"
$ foo="a"
$ eval echo "\$${foo}_x"
Hello world
```

Note the escaped dollar sign, which is used to expand the **eval**uated variable caused by expanding the first variable.

Most folks will tell you that you probably shouldn't use eval, it's dangerous and unruly. I will also tell you this, though there are cases where eval does exactly what you need and you can control its input.

Instead, bash offers something called "indirection" (which you can search for in `man bash`).  You use it like this:

```
$ a_x="Hello world"
$ foo=a
$ bar="${foo}_x"
$ echo "${!bar}"
Hello world
```

Note the extra variable.